# got 302 on form update in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel, http-status-code-302

I am facing a 302 redirect issue while posting data in for updating everything updated successfully except image where i get 302 and my page redirected.

here is my form blade code :

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['posts.update', $post->id],'data-parsley-validate' => '','class' => 'form-horizontal','files'=>true,'name'=>'updateabout']) !!}

<div class="col-md-8">

    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label"> Title : </label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control " name="title" type="text" value="{{$post->title}}" id="title">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Slug:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" name="slug" type="text" value="{{$post->slug}}" id="slug">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Category:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Tags:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ Form::select('tags[]', $tags, null, ['class' => 'form-control select2-multi', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) }}
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Short-Description:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <textarea name="short_description" class="form-control" maxlength="140" rows="7" required
                      id="shortdesc">{{$post->short_description}}</textarea>
            <script src="{{ asset("/public/admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js") }}"></script>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace('shortdesc', {
                    height: 100,
                    toolbar: 'Custom', //makes all editors use this toolbar
                    toolbarStartupExpanded: false,
                    toolbarCanCollapse: false,
                    toolbar_Custom: [] //define an empty array or whatever buttons you want.
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Date:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ Form::text('date', null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'date']) }}
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(function () {
                    $('#date').datepicker({format: 'HH:mm:ss'});
                })
            });
        </script>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label"> Image: </label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <img src="{{asset($post->image)}}" height="200" width="579">
            <input type="hidden" name="imageold" value="{{$post->image}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Change Image: </label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="imagemain" id="file">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'long_description']) }}
            <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                tinymce.init({
                    selector: '#long_description',
                    convert_urls: false,
                    statusbar: false,
                    height: '300',
                    plugins: 'image code print preview fullpage  searchreplace autolink directionality  visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link    table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking  toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount   imagetools    contextmenu colorpicker textpattern media ',
                    toolbar: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat |undo redo | image code| link fontsizeselect  | ',

                    image_title: true,
                    automatic_uploads: true,
                    images_upload_url: '{{url("/admin/upload")}}',
                    file_picker_types: 'image',
                    file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {

                        var input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

                        input.onchange = function () {
                            var file = this.files[0];

                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                            reader.onload = function () {
                                var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                                var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                                var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                                var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                                blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                                cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), {title: file.name});
                            };
                        };
                        input.click();
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Meta-title:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ Form::textarea('meta_title', null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'meta-title']) }}
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace('meta-title', {
                    height: 100,
                    toolbar: 'Custom', //makes all editors use this toolbar
                    toolbarStartupExpanded: false,
                    toolbarCanCollapse: false,
                    toolbar_Custom: [] //define an empty array or whatever buttons you want.
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Meta-Keywords:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ Form::textarea('meta_keywords', null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'meta-keywords']) }}
            <script src="{{ asset("/public/admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js") }}"></script>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace('meta-keywords', {
                    height: 100,
                    toolbar: 'Custom', //makes all editors use this toolbar
                    toolbarStartupExpanded: false,
                    toolbarCanCollapse: false,
                    toolbar_Custom: [] //define an empty array or whatever buttons you want.
                });
            </script>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Posted By:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ Form::text('authorname', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <br>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            {{ Form::submit('Update Post', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
            <a type="button" id="addslide" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and My controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Validate the data
    $postdata = Post::find($id);

    //print_r($post);

    if ($request->input('slug') == $postdata->slug) {
        //echo 'slug match';
        //exit();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title'            => 'required|max:255',
            'category_id'      => 'required|integer',
            'long_description' => 'required',
        ]);
    } else {
        //echo 'new slug matching';
        //exit();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title'            => 'required|max:255',
            'slug'             => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
            'category_id'      => 'required|integer',
            'long_description' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('imagemain')) {

        //echo 'request has old file to unlink ';
        // exit();
        //unlink($request->get('image'));
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('imagemain')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('imagemain')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('imagemain')->move('public/blogsimages', $fileNameToStore);
        // Filename to store
        echo $fileNameToStore = $path;
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = $request->input('imageold');
        // exit();
    }

    // Save the data to the database
    $post = Post::find($id);

    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->slug = $request->input('slug');
    $post->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
    $post->description = $request->input('description');
    $post->short_description = $request->input('short_description');
    $post->date = $request->input('date');
    $post->image = $fileNameToStore;
    $post->meta_title = $request->input('meta_title');
    $post->meta_keywords = $request->input('meta_keywords');
    $post->authorname = $request->input('authorname');

    $post->save();

    if (isset($request->tags)) {
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
    } else {
        $post->tags()->sync([]);
    }

    // set flash data with success message
    Session::flash('success', 'This post was successfully saved.');

    // redirect with flash data to posts.show
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

when i post data everything updated as per requirement except image and form showing 302 here is screenshots:
[image: RESPONSE FROM SERVER] 
my routes is :  `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');`

Comment: 302 status code means a redirect occurred. You are redirecting with `return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is error in validation Script 
please try the code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Validate the data
    $postdata = Post::find($id);

    //WITHOUT VALIDATION



    if ($request->hasFile('imagemain')) {

        //echo 'request has old file to unlink ';
        // exit();
        //unlink($request->get('image'));
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('imagemain')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('imagemain')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('imagemain')->move('public/blogsimages', $fileNameToStore);
        // Filename to store
        echo $fileNameToStore = $path;
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = $request->input('imageold');
        // exit();
    }

    // Save the data to the database
    $post = Post::find($id);

    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->slug = $request->input('slug');
    $post->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
    $post->description = $request->input('description');
    $post->short_description = $request->input('short_description');
    $post->date = $request->input('date');
    $post->image = $fileNameToStore;
    $post->meta_title = $request->input('meta_title');
    $post->meta_keywords = $request->input('meta_keywords');
    $post->authorname = $request->input('authorname');

    $post->save();

    if (isset($request->tags)) {
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
    } else {
        $post->tags()->sync([]);
    }

    // set flash data with success message
    Session::flash('success', 'This post was successfully saved.');

    // redirect with flash data to posts.show
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

THIS will Solve Your Problem.

Answer (score 1):

302 status code meaning:

From [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 302 Found redirect status
>   response code indicates that the resource requested has been
>   temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header

So in the last line of your controller you are performing a redirect:

```
return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
```

Also when Laravel validation fails, It redirects you automatically.

Comment: thanks for your reply @AliN11 even if i remove that line still am going to same page with no file upload main issue is ... the file has to be updated on change

Comment: OK got it checking for validation

Comment: no validation error in script everything is ok even image is saving to folder but not updating in db

Comment: @JagdishSharma I didn't find any problem with your given codes. Can you find out where does the problem come from ?

Comment: If you are redirecting back, it means that validation fails